# Sum pandas dataframe rows using column starting with same name

Tags: pandas, sum, calculated-columns

I have this DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'1_col': [1, 2], '2_col': [3, 4], 'var1': [5,6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

which looks like this:

```
    1_col  2_col  var1
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

I need to sum all the columns whose name ends in `_col`, so that the resulting DataFrame looks like this (the column called `sum` is the sum of the columns `1_col` and `2_col`:

```
    1_col  2_col  var1 sum
0     1     3     5     4
1     2     4     6     6
```

Is there a way in pandas to sum all the columns whose name ends with "_col" rather than doing it manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`df.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
In [1209]: df['sum'] = df.filter(like='_col').sum(1)

In [1210]: df
Out[1210]: 
   1_col  2_col  var1  sum
0      1      3     5    4
1      2      4     6    6
```